# How to filter out a first value of a column and then second value and then third and so on till nth using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a Excel file as below which has multiple information in it :

```
Name        list          company
 x      [xyz,mno,pqr]       xyz 
 y      [abc,rst,hij]       abc
 x      [xyz,mno,pqr]       uvw
 y      [abc,rst,hij]       def
 x      [xyz,mno,pqr]       mno
 y      [abc,rst,hij]       rst
```

and from this excel i want to apply filter in Name column and take the first value and then want to check few things and then filter second value and so on which i am explaining with an example below for first value:

Suppose I have filtered "x" from Name column then i have 3 rows , so from list column (horizontal) i need to check whether all three "xyz", "mno" and "pqr" are present in company column (vertical) or not. So, here "xyz" and "mno" are present in first and third row of company column but "pqr" is not present in any of the row. So in output i want "pqr" as shown below:

```
Name        list          company   Output
 x      [xyz,mno,pqr]       xyz       pqr
 y      [abc,rst,hij]       abc       hij
 x      [xyz,mno,pqr]       uvw       pqr
 y      [abc,rst,hij]       def       hij
 x      [xyz,mno,pqr]       mno       pqr
 y      [abc,rst,hij]       rst       hij
```

It looks very complex to me and I am unable to get to any code or solution. Your help will really be appreciated.

As per the suggestion I have used below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


frame=pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx")

frame_Liste=frame.Liste.values.tolist()
frame_company=frame.company.values.tolist()
frame_col3=[]

for items in frame_Liste:
    frame_col3.append(list(set(items)-set(frame_company)))

frame["output"]=frame_col3

frame.to_excel("df.xlsx", index = False)
```

However I am getting output but the output is wrong and weird.I am showing you the output below:

[Link for Output I got from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tg5z.png)

Comment: check with str.split

Comment: `df['Odd_One'] = df['list'].str.split(',',expand=True)[1]` should work

Comment: your second "x" has the list [xyz,pqr] and the company name is "uvw", your Odd_number is "pqr". Is there a typo in the company name, i.e. should it be xyz?

Is it possible that in the list the company name is not included?

Comment: No, there is no typo mistake. The list is like that and there is long list from which we need to search the odd one out by filtering the name column. It is like we need to search from horizontal list for odd one out by considering the vertical filtered name column. Please let me know if you have got the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please be more specific about your problem, i.e. that you have the data in a sheet. Also please take care on your notation, since "[]" means list in python. Thus it was confusing. Now after you wrote that your data is in an excel sheet the problem is clear

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_excel("path")
frame_Liste_as_String=frame.Liste.tolist()
frame_Liste=[x.split(',') for x in frame_Liste_as_String]
frame_Company=frame.Company.tolist()
frame_col3=[]
for items in frame_Liste:
    frame_col3.append(list(set(items)-set(frame_Company)))

frame["col3"]=frame_col3

  Name        Liste Company   col3
0    x  xyz,mno,pqr     xyz  [pqr]
1    y  abc,rst,hij     abc  [hij]
2    x  xyz,mno,pqr     uvw  [pqr]
3    y  abc,rst,hij     def  [hij]
4    x  xyz,mno,pqr     mno  [pqr]
5    y  abc,rst,hij     rst  [hij]
```

That should solve your problem

**In case your data in the Liste Column is really in brackets change the line to**

```
frame_Liste=[x.strip('][').split(',') for x in frame_Liste_as_String]
```

Comment: I am getting an error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" on running the above code. Could you please help me.

Comment: Also I have applied pd.Series to avoid this error and then the code worked but output was not correct.

Comment: The error comes up when you are trying to assign a list of numpy array of different length to a data frame

Do you get the error if you repeat my example?

Comment: Instead of `frame["Output"]=np.array(frame_col3).flatten()` just do `frame["Output"]=frame_col3`

Comment: Yes, I am still getting no output and the above error is coming "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" after doing as per your example. Have changed the "frame["Output"]=np.array(frame_col3).flatten()" to "frame["Output"] = frame_col3" but no output generated.

Comment: Please repeat my example step my step and text when do you get the error. Because I did today the example again and I dont get any error.

Comment: Kindly look at the code I have included at the bottom of my question if it is correct or not as I am not getting the output. Only the last line ""frame["Output"]=np.array(frame_col3).flatten()" is creating problem

Comment: As I said, write `frame["output"]=frame_col3`. That should solve your issue, **but outside the loop** Keep me updated please

Comment: I have edited the code as per u said and the code gave the output which is weird and incorrect. I have given the link of obtained output at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Above code worked successfully. Thanks a lot for your help :)